# How to pass value from one immediate invoking function (IIFE) to an another invoking function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web

Suppose you have two immediate invoking functions - **example1** and **example2**.
how to receive a value from example2 to example1? or how to call a method from example2 ?

```
let example1 = (function(testvalue){

   // Receive value from example2 function.

})(example2);



let example2 = (function(){
       let _testvalue = 12;
       return{
               getvalue : function(){
                     return _testvalue;
                } 
              }

    })();
```

Comment: pass `example2.getvalue()` instead of just `example2` to the first IIFE?

Comment: The order is important here. Execute example2 first.

Comment: example 2 isn't defined yet. this can't work

Comment: so example2.getvalue() should be passed as an argument insted of the argument example2 ??

Comment: @alexanto yes, OR you call `testvalue.getvalue()` inside the IIFE represented by `example1`. But first, as others have said, you need to put `example2` before `example1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**example2 must be executed first (otherwise the variable will just be hoisted and be undefined)**

Then there's two ways to do it:

```
let example2 = (function(){
   let _testvalue = 12;
   return{
           getvalue : function(){
                 return _testvalue;
            } 
          }

})();

//way 1
var example1 = (function(testvalue){

   // Receive value from example2 function.
   console.log(testvalue.getvalue());

})(example2);

//way 2
var example1 = (function(testvalue){

   // Receive value from example2 function.
   console.log(testvalue);

})(example2.getvalue());
```